# Django Haystack w/ Elasticsearch Dwithin Wrong Projection or Units?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, geodjango

I am trying to add geolocation to my search API. In the API, you can search for businesses, based on a search term and your current location. I am using django haystack for indexing and querying, everything is working save for one curious problem.

When I search with a radius of 5 miles (`D(mi=5)`), I don't see any results, even though there are clearly results within a 5 mile radius of the location entered. But then when I enter 100 miles (`D(mi=100)`), I do see results, which are within 1 mile of the location entered.

**Question**: Is it possible the Distance class (`D`) is using a different projection than WGS-84?

Here is my iPython shell session:

```
In [5]: from haystack.utils.geo import D

In [6]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

In [7]: dist = D(mi=5)

In [8]: point = Point(-122.256013, 37.864203)

In [9]: SearchQuerySet().dwithin('location', point, dist)
Out[9]: []

In [10]: dist2 = D(mi=100)

In [11]: sqs = SearchQuerySet().dwithin('location', point, dist).distance('location', point2)

In [12]: sqs
Out[12]: [<SearchResult: api.business (pk=u'3232')>, <SearchResult: api.business (pk=u'3238')>]

In [13]: sqs[0].distance
Out[13]: Distance(km=0.140045623232) << This is correct
```

#### Versions

*Python Libraries*

- Django: 1.7
- pyelasticsearch: 1.2.0
- geopy: 1.3.0
- django-haystack: 2.3.1

*External Dependencies*

- GDAL: 1.11.0
- GEOS: 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, i fixed it upgrading django-haystack to [2.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-haystack/2.4.0)

Elasticsearch handled kilometers as meters (see: [issue-957](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/957) and [pr-1003](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1003)).